# How to change the state of Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox control in .aspx page. Now in my c# code I am able to find out the checked/Unchecked state of the control with below line

```
  CheckBox objCheckBox = (CheckBox)objGridRecord.Items[0].FindControl("chNo");
```

Now I need to change the Checked state of my control to Unchecked, but not able to get the right way.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `objCheckBox.Checked = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have obtained your control as a `CheckBox` object, you can change its state just like any other `CheckBox`:

```
objCheckbBox.Checked = false;
```

See also the official documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx